# How to add Sceneform dependency into build.gradle?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I want to use SceneForm in my Android app. Adding into the build.gradle (app level) a dependency like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.36.0' // also added
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1'
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.17.1'
```

causes a problem with duplicated class:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
```

and some other close to this.

When I delete the `sceneform-ux` dependency, all gets to normal.

Google Developers website says that `sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux` provides ArFragment and some UX resources, whereas `sceneform:core` adds ArSceneView and does not contain UX. But as far as I've found out, ARFragment is deprecated. Should I add only `sceneform:core` to use SceneForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done was to google and see that here is Sceneform community on GitHub — https://github.com/sceneview, where I've found some info.
The dependency must look like: 
`implementation "com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.21.0"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to try downgrading in one of the dependencies, the conflict might go away if the conflict is between google dependencies.